# How to call function after ngApp finished processing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS module definition. I wish to run some code once this module is done processing.

```
var app = angular.module("Enlightks_Dashboard", ["RoomAvailabilityWidget", "TwitterNewsWidget", "BirthdayWidget", "TelephoneDataWidget", "AnnouncementWidget"]);

app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function(){});
  }]);
```

Per suggestion, I tried using the `run` block, but the callback is not being called as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish after all ?

Comment: Is the `run` method what you're looking for? (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run)[run]

Comment: Where is the callback coming from exactly? `run` is not the DOMContentLoaded event. What is `$.connection.hub.start();`? I don't really want to sow the seeds here, so I'm reluctant to add that you should wrap `$.connection.hub.start();' in a DOM ready event and that could do what you're trying to get done.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in the `run` block. Observe the following...

```
var app = angular.module("Enlightks_Dashboard", ["RoomAvailabilityWidget", "TwitterNewsWidget", "BirthdayWidget", "TelephoneDataWidget", "AnnouncementWidget"]);

app.run(function() {
    console.log('boom'); // all dependent modules injected and ready
});
```

be sure to check out the [module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for more information

> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the services have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/haczf8ua/) - simple demo with injection per your comments

Comment: I tried using the run function, but the callback function wasn't being called updated code is above

Comment: @AbdulRahamanAbdullah you seem to be declaring it wrong, why are you passing `""` as the first argument? If you are trying to define this in min-safe fashion, do so correctly with the array `[]` syntax

Comment: I made changes to the above code, however the app.run is being called before all the other modules have finished being loaded, and not after.

Comment: I need to register client functions, before starting the client hub proxy. I don't need to call the server. Which is registered inside the done callback

Comment: okay, regardless of the signalr client, that `run` block will fire after every dependency is injected. Did you read the snippet and docs? There is no way `run` is firing before all dependencies are loaded